# getElementById returns null even though its in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to find my element in my HTML file, but it returns null even though its there. 
I cant find something wrong with my code, neither in the html.
I read the other suggested threads on stackoverflow and have already wrapped it in an onload function, but it still not seem to work.

**This is my JS file**

```
window.onload = run();
function run(){
  var archived = localStorage.getItem("arkiv");
  console.log(archived)
  var array = archived.split(",");
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    console.log(array[i])
    var getUL = document.getElementById("archivedmovies")
    console.log(getUL)
    var li = document.createElement(li);
    li.innerHTML = array[i];
    getUL.appendChild(li);
  }
};
```

**This is the HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="sv">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/jquery.form/3.50/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="anton.jpg">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Movietime">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.js">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="anton.png">
        <title>Film-appen</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

                <!-- Navigation -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Film-appen</a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"> Sök film</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="inst.html">Ladda upp filer</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="files.html"> Mina uppladdningar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Mitt filmbibliotek</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="container" id="userinfo">
                              <p><strong>Användare:</strong></p>
                              <p> Philip </p>
                              <p><strong>Favoritfilm:</strong></p>
                              <p id="getFavMovie">  </p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
              </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="archivedmovies">
          <h4 class="text-center"> Arkiverade filmer </h4>
          <ul id="listofmovies">

          </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js.js"> </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you give more detail on how is it *not working*?

Comment: @ChanMT it's in the title: it returns `null`.

Comment: Could it be you are mistaking `null` of `archived` with `null` of `getUL`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca But it does not return null... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLpQpE?editors=1111. I think the `localStorage` is culprit here.

Comment: i think there is an error getting value try somthing as var getUL = document.getElementById("archivedmovies").innerHTML

Comment: Nothing wrong.Check my codepen-https://codepen.io/NullPointerr/pen/YOyRqB?editors=1111

Comment: `already wrapped it in an onload function` no you did not. `window.onload = run()` executes `run()` and assigns the result returned by `run` to `window.onload` writing, `window.onload = run;` would execute the function `run` on load. But if the given code is in the `js.js` file which is loaded at the end of the document, then this should not be the problem.

Comment: One issue I see is that the call to createElement should provide a string for a parameter, like `'li'`. And another is that the list elements should be appended to `listofmovies`, not to `archivedmovies`. But neither of those issues can't cause the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is not get `getElementById returns null`

but this line

```
  var archived = localStorage.getItem("arkiv");
```

Could you please specify if you are really storing the value at localstorage?

Your element is found, check the result before the error (localstorage security error, specific to stackoverflow)

```js
window.onload = run();
function run(){
  console.log(document.getElementById("archivedmovies"));
  var archived = localStorage.getItem("arkiv");
  console.log(archived)
  var array = archived.split(",");
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    console.log(array[i])
    var getUL = document.getElementById("archivedmovies")
    console.log(getUL)
    var li = document.createElement(li);
    li.innerHTML = array[i];
    getUL.appendChild(li);
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="sv">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/jquery.form/3.50/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="anton.jpg">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Movietime">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.js">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="anton.png">
        <title>Film-appen</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

                <!-- Navigation -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Film-appen</a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"> Sök film</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="inst.html">Ladda upp filer</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="files.html"> Mina uppladdningar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Mitt filmbibliotek</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="container" id="userinfo">
                              <p><strong>Användare:</strong></p>
                              <p> Philip </p>
                              <p><strong>Favoritfilm:</strong></p>
                              <p id="getFavMovie">  </p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
              </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="archivedmovies">
          <h4 class="text-center"> Arkiverade filmer </h4>
          <ul id="listofmovies">

          </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js.js"> </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks more a problem with your local storage array perhaps? If I code archived by hand the loop is run and object found....

```
window.onload = run();
function run(){
  var archived = 'asddasdasd,asdsdasdas'
  console.log(archived)
  var array = archived.split(",");
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    console.log(array[i])
    var getUL = document.getElementById("archivedmovies")
    alert(getUL);
    var li = document.createElement(li);
    li.innerHTML = array[i];
    getUL.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1hwdaL4c/3/